# Как правильно: "познания о чем-либо" или "познания в чем-либо"?

Tags: синтаксис, фразеология

Мне кажется, нельзя говорить "познания о...", только "познания в...".
Но это мое субъективное мнение, доказательств, кроме "чувства языка", у меня нет.
В Корпусе 100 примеров использования "познания о...".
Что скажете?
Спасибо!

Comment: Не скажешь "познания в тиграх", "познания в сравнительных оборотах", "познания в Марсе". Зависит от существительного.

Comment: здесь, мне кажется, вообще некорректно использовать "познания", потому что тигры - это не область знаний, а вот биология - область. поэтому познания в биологии

Comment: "Познания о тиграх" вполне корректно. Полно примеров не с областью знаний. А "познания о биологии" означает знания о самой науке, а не о предметах её изучения, но это экзотический случай.

Answer (score 1):

Познания В - указывает на область применения познаний, где или к чему это познание применимо, на класс объектов, объединенных понятием, на среду, где это познание получено: познание в школе, познание в них и тп. В-сочетается с предикатом познания, то есть условием вот этих знаний - школьные знания...

Познания О - это формирование понимания о каком-то предмете, явлении или понятии. Не в школе как в месте, а о школе - как о процессе обучения. Познания о - более общее представление.

То есть В предполагает конкретизацию чего-то или в фокусировку в чём-то, что является источником знания/познания, а О - наоборот расширяет область поиска, но то что "о" становится не источником знания, а целью познания. То есть, получить знания в школе - школа не цель изучения, а средство, только там ты получишь знания или познания о чем-то, а познания о школе - нахождение внутри школьных правил, не дает полноты понимания, потому что понимание "о школе" лежит за её пределами, познания о книге - прочтение книги, содержание книги на дает понимания причин, причины находятся вне познаваемого предмета книги/сюжета.

Comment: У   вас всегда очень интересные рассуждения о языке, но во словарь, что с ним делать… Он разрешает два управления: познание (чего? беспредложный Р.п.) и познаниЯ (в чем, П.п.). ПОЗНАНИЕ, -я; ср. 1. Процесс приобретения знаний, постижения закономерностей объективного мира. Теория познания. 2. к Познать. П. законов природы. П. мира ребёнком. Научное п. 3. мн.: ПОЗНАНИЯ, -ий. Совокупность знаний в какой-л. области. Приобрести познания в архитектуре. Иметь некоторые познания в немецком языке. Проверить познания ученика в орфографии.

Comment: Проверить познания ученика в орфографии. - да, возможно, хотя сейчас скажут "проверить знания", но  "Проверить познания ученика о орфографии" - не верно. Потому что "познание/я о" не выступает в качестве объекта управлении. О - это что-то отглагольное, рассказ о друге, рассказывать о друге/рассказ в друге(уже чепуха), рассказывать в друге(тоже). То есть познания о друге - познавания о друге. Так что "познание о" - это к первому значению, познание - процесс, познавание процессов. А "познания в" - это совокупность знаний в области. Получать/ить познания в, достичь познания о.

Comment: Возможно, тут еще путается множественное число и родительный падеж?

Comment: А как они могут путаться? Схема такая: знать/познать (что?), знание/познание (чего?). Это обычный переход от глагола к отглагольному существительному, от В.п. к Р.п. Познания –  это много знаний, совокупность, то есть своеобразное пространство знаний.  Мы как бы заходим В это пространство. А предлог О – мы смотрим на это пространство  сверху или со стороны, как бы и не заходя туда. Просто даем оценку всему пространству.

Comment: Так, а предложения приведете, примеры?

Comment: Я люблю поэзию, люблю говорить о поэзии и о стихах любимых поэтов. Но я не очень разбираюсь в теории стихосложения и в стихах с этой точки зрения.

Comment: хорошо, а теперь существительное перед предлогами.

Comment: Виктор Пелевин(2011)  Не знаю только, каковы ваши познания в этой области...  И. Ю. Стогов (2001)  Его познания в английском ограничивались фразами «Как тебя зовут?» и «Откуда ты?»